# How can I minify html, css, js/jquery and ruby code inside Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

Running Windows 7. What is the best Sublime Text 3 plugin to do this, and maybe beautify the code as well.

Comment: depends. what kind of code are we talking about? CSS? JS? Sass?

Comment: @MattDMo Appended question :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may have already found something you like by now, but I just ran across this same need and have tried out two plugins: [*Minifier*](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Minifier) and [*Clientside*](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Clientside). *Clientside* has more features like linting and beautifying but is only compatible up to ST2 (according to its Package Control page), whereas *Minifier* should be compatible with ST3.

Comment: No, it's still been bugging me these months :P I'll give those a look in, thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 10):

May be useful, this shortcut will erase all line breaks of the selected text

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>

Notice this is not really minify, since it doesn't consider the code language.

Answer (score 6):

**Updated 8. 4. 2015 as many things have changed**

I've been looking for such ST3 plugin as well. I've tried [Sublime HTML5 Minifier](https://github.com/geekpradd/sublime-html5-minifier) by [geekpradd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4112903/geekpradd) and [Minify](https://github.com/tssajo/Minify) by [Zoltan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2302237/zoltan), both seem as great options. See their pros and cons.

**HTML5 Minifier**

- Only minifies, cannot beautify (so far)
- Doesn't restructure your CSS or JavaScript files, only removes white space and comments
- Not as effective as Minify, but keeps the code readable after beautification
- Works for HTML, CSS and JS without trouble
- Can minify the code in the current view without creating new files or saving anything
- Easy installation, doesn't require Node.js or anything else
- Has a typo in console - HTML Minfier instead of HTML Min**i**fier. But maybe it's on purpose :)

**Minify**

- Minifies and beautifies
- Restructure your CSS and JavaScript files, renames JS variables, function names etc.
- Super effective, smallest file sizes possible, but the code is changed by the minification process
- Works for HTML, CSS and JS without trouble, also should support SVG (haven't tested)
- Can't minify the code in the current view without creating new files or saving anything, minification always creates a new .min. or .beatified. file in the same directory
- A bit more complicated installation, requires Node.js and some other Node.js CLI apps

**Which plugin is better?**

There is no straightforward answer for that. Minify is more effective, so as long as all you care about is the smallest file size possible, Minify is your choice. I personally use both of these as in some cases, HTML5 Minifier may be a better choice in some cases.

I'm just hoping that [Zoltan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2302237/zoltan), the Minify developer, will add the crucial functionality to minify the current buffer without creating or saving any file just like [geekpradd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4112903/geekpradd) did.

Comment: I'm the developer of Sublime HTML5 Minifier. @TeeJay, You should have opened an issue thread on my github repo and I would have added your required features.

Comment: I am overhauling the plugin in Version 2.0 with more features like the ones given above. I'll try to add all of them but the Beautification thing does not match with what the plugin needs. Stay tuned with the Github repo for changes: https://github.com/geekpradd/sublime-html5-minifier

Comment: You are in luck. i found a Python module for Beautifying HTML, CSS and JS and I am integrating the module with the Plugin. https://github.com/berniey/html5print/blob/master/html5print/

Comment: @geekpradd, I didn't want to bother anyone with my requests. So far I've been fine with online tools. Anyway, your comments made me happy, I'm looking forward to trying out the new version!

Comment: I have implemented most of your required features except the Beautification thing which is turning out to be very heavy.  And some OS X bug fixing is needed to be done otherwise all is implemented. You might  want to install the plugin again and check it out. If you face any problems open an issue thread on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks, now it's much more of what I needed.

Comment: @TeeJay, thank you for mentioning Minify which I am the author of. As of version 1.1.0+ of Minify I use Node.js CLI apps only, so you only need to install Node.js which is very very simple and then install a few CLI apps written in Node.js which can be done with a single npm command. For CSS minifying now I use the clean-css CLI app which is extremely effective, probably the best. Please consider trying Minify again. Thanks!

Comment: I'd never though that my simple answer mentioning the Sublime Text plugins would be ever read by the authors of the mentioned plugins. I'll definitely give it a try again, thanks Zoltan for your information.

Comment: So I've tried it. CSS minification is amazing, it not only removes white space, but it also edits the CSS to optimize it, that's perfect and makes the file even smaller. I'm just missing the option to minify what I have in the current buffer/view without creating a new file, just minify what I'm seeing without creating or saving any file. Useful when working with files over FTP as these files are temporarily stored somewhere in Windows temp and I don't want to minify a file to the temp. JS minification is also super efficient as it renames variables and function names to letters

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old question, but here is my answer anyway:

I recommend you to visit the excellent [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/) website and perform a search for the keyword "minify"

You will get a list of various packages for the Sublime Text editor which provide the requested functionality (minifying / beautifying).

Disclosure: I am the author of one of the packages listed on the [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/) website: [Minify](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Minify).

I am not saying that my package is best for everyone, but Minify is the package I use, obviously.

Note: I'm also on Windows 7. My [Minify](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Minify) package works in both Sublime Text 2 and Sublime Text 3. Once installed, it works offline, so you can even minify your files while you are not connected to the Internet.

Comment: Please consider to add this feature: I'm just hoping that Zoltan, the Minify developer, will add the crucial functionality to minify the current buffer without creating or saving any file just like geekpradd did.